# Calculating average from array - How to return null if empty

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and I'm working on an assignment to create a function that calculates the average using the numbers in an array. If the array is `[]`, it should return `null`.

I have the following code so far but it keeps returning `NaN` instead of `null`, can someone please explain this to me? Thanks in advance.

```
function mean(arr) {
  if (arr == []) {
    return null;
  } else {
    var sum = 0;
    var average = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      sum += arr[i];
    }
    return round(sum / arr.length);
  }
}



console.log(mean([6,2,3,3,110,6,1,0,5])); //returns 4
console.log(mean([])); //currently returning NaN, instead of null
```

Comment: Try: `if (arr.length === 0)`. Also, `round` should be `Math.round`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. Just change `arr == []` to `arr.length == 0`.

```
    function mean(arr) {
    if (arr.length == 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        var sum = 0;
        var average = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          sum += arr[i];
        }
        return Math.round(sum / arr.length);
        }
    }

    console.log(mean([6,2,3,3,110,6,1,0,5])); //returns 4
    console.log(mean([])); //currently returning NaN, instead of null
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of the array using `arr.length ===0`

```js
function mean(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return null;
  } else {
    var sum = 0;
    var average = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      sum += arr[i];
    }
    return round(sum / arr.length);
  }
}




console.log(mean([]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Added additional condition to check if the variable is not an array to avoid runtime exception.

```
function mean(arr) {
If (arr.constructor != Array) return null;
if (arr.length == 0) {
    return null;
} else {
    var sum = 0;
    var average = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      sum += arr[i];
    }
    return Math.round(sum / arr.length);
    }
}
```